# ADO FireDac equivalent

Tags: delphi, firedac

i found some example about sorting algorithm for devexpress grid mode true. But this example writing with ADO. But i am working with firedac.

Could you tell me, what is the equivalent of CommandText and InitSQL in Firedac. I am searching on google but i couldn' t find . Thank you, i also share all code :

```
var    
 i, ID: Integer;    
 Several: Boolean;    
 SQLOrderSt: string;    
...

   with TADODataset(<View>.DataController.DataSource.DataSet) do    
   begin    
     ID := FieldByName('CustNo').AsInteger;    
     DisableControls;    
     try    
       Close;    
       SQLOrderSt := '';    
       Several := False;    
       for i := 0 to <View>.SortedItemCount - 1 do    
       begin    
         if Several then    
           SQLOrderSt := SQLOrderSt + ', ';    
         SQLOrderSt := SQLOrderSt + TcxGridDBColumn(<View>.SortedItems[I]).DataBinding.FieldName;    
         Several := True;    
         if <View>.SortedItems[i].SortOrder = soDescending then    
           SQLOrderSt := SQLOrderSt + ' DESC';    
       end;

       if SQLOrderSt <> '' then    
         SQLOrderSt := 'ORDER BY ' + SQLOrderSt;    
       CommandText := InitSQL + SQLOrderSt;    
       Open;    
       Locate('CustNo', ID, []);    
     finally    
       EnableControls;    
     end;    
   end;
```

Comment: This example is closing the dataset, adding fields to the order statement and a 'DESC', adding the order statement to the SQL clause and opens the dataset. After that is doing a locate on the previous CustNo ID. What you want to accomplish with FireDac?

Comment: Several FireDAC components *have* a commandtext property. What components are you using? Where is your FireDAC code?

Comment: @RBA i am working with big data, and if i close the grid mode, data is loading too slow. I thought may be they using different technic in sorting ? TDataSource

Comment: This code is using modifications to a SQL statement to do the ordering. What part is unclear about that?

Comment: BTW This is ugly code, It pulls the rug from under your DevExpress grid by closing the underlying dataset and re-opening it with a new query. I'm not saying it can't be done (lack of 'experience' doing this) but it looks suspicious. What's wrong with letting the grid handling the sorting?